# Overlapping communications with computations in MPI (mvapich2) for large messages

Tags: c, performance, mpi

I have a very simple code, a data decomposition problem in which in a loop each process sends two large messages to the ranks before and after itself at each cycle. I run this code in a cluster of SMP nodes (AMD Magny cores, 32 core per node, 8 cores per socket). It's a while I'm in the process of optimizing this code. I have used pgprof and tau for profiling and it looks to me that the bottleneck is the communication. I have tried to overlap the communication with the computations in my code however it looks that the actual communication starts when the computations finish :(

I use persistent communication in ready mode (MPI_Rsend_init) and in between the MPI_Start_all and MPI_Wait_all bulk of the computation is done. The code looks like this:

```
void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  some definitions;
  some initializations;

  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

  MPI_Rsend_init( channel to the rank before );
  MPI_Rsend_init( channel to the rank after );
  MPI_Recv_init( channel to the rank before );
  MPI_Recv_init( channel to the rank after );

  for (timestep=0; temstep<Time; timestep++)
  {
    prepare data for send;
    MPI_Start_all();

    do computations;

    MPI_Wait_all();

    do work on the received data;
  }
  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Unfortunately the actual data transfer does not start until the computations are done, I don't understand why. The network uses QDR InfiniBand Interconnect and mvapich2. each message size is 23MB (totally 46 MB message is sent). I tried to change the message passing to eager mode, since the memory in the system is large enough. I use the following flags in my job script:
    MV2_SMP_EAGERSIZE=46M
    MV2_CPU_BINDING_LEVEL=socket
    MV2_CPU_BINDING_POLICY=bunch

Which gives me an improvement of about 8%, probably because of better placement of the ranks inside the SMP nodes however still the problem with communication remains. My question is why can't I effectively overlap the communications with the computations? Is there any flag that I should use and I'm missing it? I know something is wrong, but whatever I have done has not been enough.

By the order of ranks inside the SMP nodes the actual message sizes between the nodes is also 46MB (2x23MB) and the ranks are in a loop. Can you please help me? To see the flags that other users use I have checked /etc/mvapich2.conf however it is empty.

Is there any other method that I should use? do you think one sided communication gives better performance? I feel there is a flag or something that I'm not aware of.

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is something called *progression of operations* in MPI. The standard allows for non-blocking operations to only be progressed to completion once the proper testing/waiting call was made:

> A nonblocking **send start** call initiates the send operation, but does not complete it. The send start call can return before the message was copied out of the send buffer. A separate **send complete** call is needed to complete the communication, i.e., to verify that the data has been copied out of the send buffer. *With suitable hardware, the transfer of data out of the sender memory may proceed concurrently with computations done at the sender after the send was initiated and before it completed.* Similarly, a nonblocking **receive start call** initiates the receive operation, but does not complete it. The call can return before a message is stored into the receive buffer. A separate **receive complete** call is needed to complete the receive operation and verify that the data has been received into the receive buffer. *With suitable hardware, the transfer of data into the receiver memory may proceed concurrently with computations done after the receive was initiated and before it completed.*

(words in **bold** are also bolded in the standard text; emphasis added by me)

Although this text comes from the section about non-blocking communication (§3.7 of MPI-3.0; the text is exactly the same in MPI-2.2), it also applies to persistent communication requests.

I haven't used MVAPICH2, but I am able to speak about how things are implemented in Open MPI. Whenever a non-blocking operation is initiated or a persistent communication request is started, the operation is added to a queue of pending operations and is then progressed in one of the two possible ways:

- if Open MPI was compiled without an asynchronous progression thread, outstanding operations are progressed on each call to a send/receive or to some of the wait/test operations;
- if Open MPI was compiled with an asynchronous progression thread, operations are progressed in the background even if no further communication calls are made.

The default behaviour is not to enable the asynchronous progression thread as doing so increases the latency of the operations somehow.

The MVAPICH site is unreachable at the moment from here, but earlier I saw a mention of asynchronous progress in the features list. Probably that's where you should start from - search for ways to enable it.

Also note that `MV2_SMP_EAGERSIZE` controls the shared memory protocol eager message size and does not affect the InfiniBand protocol, i.e. it can only improve the communication between processes that reside on the same cluster node.

By the way, there is no guarantee that the receive operations would be started before the ready send operations in the neighbouring ranks, so they might not function as expected as the ordering in time is very important there.

Comment: Thanks man, it was really helpful, I did a complete search about it however still I'm not successful, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

For MPICH, you can set `MPICH_ASYNC_PROGRESS=1` environment variable when runing mpiexec/mpirun. This will spawn a background process which does "asynchronous progress" stuff.

> MPICH_ASYNC_PROGRESS - Initiates a spare thread to provide
>            asynchronous progress. This improves progress semantics for
>            all MPI operations including point-to-point, collective,
>            one-sided operations and I/O. Setting this variable would
>            increase the thread-safety level to
>            MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE. While this improves the progress
>            semantics, it might cause a small amount of performance
>            overhead for regular MPI operations.

from [MPICH Environment Variables](https://www.mpich.org/static/downloads/3.0.4/mpich-3.0.4-README.txt)

I have tested on my cluster with MPICH-3.1.4, it worked! I believe MVAPICH will also work.